# A frase "É raro a doença do carrapato em cachorros, principalmente, em humanos" está correta?

Tags: gramática, sintaxe, pontuação

A frase "É raro a doença do carrapato em cachorros, principalmente, em humanos" está correta?
Se ela estiver errada, porque?

Answer (score 3):

A frase me parece mal construída, senão por ferir a gramática padrão, pelo menos por ser confusa.

Por exemplo:

> É raro [...] em cachorros, principalmente, em humanos

parece implicar que humanos são uma categoria de cachorros (cf. "É raro tubarões atacarem, principalmente tubarões-baleia."), e vejo uma vírgula sobrando depois de "principalmente".

Se minha interpretação da frase estiver correta, penso que ela poderia ficar mais clara da seguinte maneira:

> É raro a doença do carrapato [**dar**] em cachorros **e**, principalmente, em humanos.

Comment: Na sua interpretação, significa que a doença é mais rara em humanos do que em cachorros?

Comment: @DanGetz Sim, se a frase original pode ser reescrita como coloquei nessa última (com "dar" e "e"), essa é a interpretação a que me refiro — em que, aliás, "principalmente" também não é uma escolha tão boa (algo como "ainda mais" sendo mais claro).

Answer (score 2):

Numa norma mais padrão, esperar-se-ia o adjetivo no feminino, uma vez que o adjetivo "raro" deve concordar com o nome "doença", que é feminino.

> "É **rara** a doença do carrapato em cachorros..."

Mas se o adjetivo estiver em posição predicativa (isto é, depois do verbo "ser") em algo como a frase a seguir, está tudo bem.

> "É **raro** a doença do carrapato estar no cachorro".

A frase que você sugeriu também pode ocorrer, imagino, por conta de um expletivo antes do verbo ser, mas aí é outra história na qual não me aprofundarei! Portanto, está correta, só não é muito padrão.

Comment: As virgulas não estão estranhas também? Quando vi a frase pela primeira vez a primeira coisa que estranhei foi o uso da vírgula

Comment: @GustavoHK, sim, um pouco, eu tiraria a vírgula entre "principalmente" e "em humanos", ou colocaria um "e" depois de "cachorros"!

Comment: @Schilive, obrigado pela observação, vou editar e explicar!

Comment: Eu diria que o "estar" (ou ainda "dar", "ser encontrada", etc.) da frase "É raro a doença do carrapato [dar] em cachorros." também pode estar subtendido.

Comment: @stafusa, sim, poderia também

Answer (score 1):

Acho que a frase poderia ser reescrita do seguinte modo, para ser mais inteligível: "A doença do carrapato é rara em cachorros e mais ainda em humanos". Nesse caso, 'rara' (predicativo) deve concordar com 'doença' (núcleo do sujeito), pois temos um verbo de ligação (é). Se incluirmos um infinitivo, como foi sugerido acima, então, teremos que usar 'raro', pois a concordância se dará agora com um sujeito oracional no infinitivo (verbo + doença do carrapato). Exemplo: "É raro ocorrer a doença do carrapato em cachorros e mais [raro] ainda [ocorrer] em humanos". Espero que isso ajude, caso eu não esteja equivocado.

Comment: Seja muito bem-vindo, Cássio Vieira, ao Portuguese StackExchange! Muito obrigado pela contribuição, mas, pelo que li, você não respondeu à pergunta, mas fez apenas um comentário, e publicou como resposta. Você poderia, talvez, responder à pergunta e, então, adicionar um comentário à sua resposta. De qualquer modo, obrigado pela contribuição!

Comment: Muito obrigado! Sim, seguirei sua sugestão.